# Задержка при считывании RFID - меток. Help

Tags: c#, terminal

Есть девайс Motorola MC9090G1 (Терминал Сбора Данных) в SDK к нему есть пример который по сути и является моей задачей, а задача по сути считать RFID-метку при помощи этого терминала и отобразить ее в списке. В этом примере считываются метки и выводятся в список. Но проблема в том, что добавление меток в список происходит не "мгновенно", а существенной задержкой это и нужно поправить. Вот код:

```
/// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main() 
    {
        ReaderForm rf = new ReaderForm();
        rf.DoScale();
        Application.Run(rf);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs before the form is displayed for the first time.
    /// </summary>
    private void ReaderForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Add MainMenu if Pocket PC
        if (Symbol.Win32.PlatformType.IndexOf("PocketPC") != -1)
        {
            this.Menu = new MainMenu();
        }

        // If we can initialize the Reader
        if ( !this.InitReader() )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to initialize RFID!","Error");

            // If not, close this form
            this.Close();

            return;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Application is closing
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // Terminate reader
        this.TermReader();

        base.OnClosing(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize the reader.
    /// </summary>
    private bool InitReader()
    {
        // If reader is already present then fail initialize
        if ( this.MyReader != null )
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            // Create new reader, first available reader will be used.
            this.MyReader = new Symbol.RFID.Reader();

            // Create reader data to read upto 20 tags
            this.MyReaderData = new Symbol.RFID.ReaderData(20);

            // Enable reader
            this.MyReader.Actions.Enable();

            // Attach handler for read notification
            this.MyEventHandler = new EventHandler(MyReader_ReadNotify);
            this.MyReader.ReadNotify += this.MyEventHandler;

            // Attach handler for trigger notification
            this.MyTriggerHandler = new Symbol.RFID.Reader.TriggerEventHandler(MyTrigger_Pressed);
            this.MyReader.TriggerNotify += this.MyTriggerHandler;

            // Attach to activate and deactivate events
            this.Activated += new EventHandler(ReaderForm_Activated);
            this.Deactivate +=new EventHandler(ReaderForm_Deactivate);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stop reading and disable/close reader
    /// </summary>
    private void TermReader()
    {
        // If we have a reader
        if ( this.MyReader != null )
        {
            // Remove read notification handler
            this.MyReader.ReadNotify -= null;

            // Attempt to stop any pending read
            this.StopRead();

            // Disable reader, with wait cursor
            this.MyReader.Actions.Disable();

            // Free it up
            this.MyReader.Dispose();

            // Indicate we no longer have one
            this.MyReader = null;
        }

        // If we have a reader data
        if ( this.MyReaderData != null )
        {
            // Free it up
            this.MyReaderData.Dispose();

            // Indicate we no longer have one
            this.MyReaderData = null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Start a read on the reader
    /// </summary>
    private void StartRead()
    {
        this.StatusLabel.Text = "Reading ...";

        // If the flag is set then start a new TagList
        if (ClearListFlag)
            this.MyReaderData.ClearInventory = true;
        else
            this.MyReaderData.ClearInventory = false;

        // If we have both a reader and a reader data
        if((this.MyReader != null) && (this.MyReaderData != null))
        {
            // Submit a read
            this.MyReader.Actions.Read(this.MyReaderData);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stop all reads on the reader
    /// </summary>
    private void StopRead()
    {
        // If we have a reader
        if ( this.MyReader != null )
        {
            // Prevent new reads
            this.MyReader.TriggerNotify -= this.MyTriggerHandler;

            // Disable the timer
            this.ReaderTimer.Enabled = false;

            // Try to cancel pending read or wait for it's completion
            this.MyReader.Actions.Flush();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles Stage2 Notification from the trigger
    /// </summary>
    private void MyTrigger_Pressed(object sender, Symbol.RFID.TriggerEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( e.NewState == Symbol.RFID.TriggerState.STAGE2 )
        {
            this.StatusLabel.Text = "Trigger Pressed. Reader Busy...";

            // If another RFID operation has not already started
            if (!this.MyReader.Info.IsBusy)
            {
                // Start a new read
                this.StartRead();
            }

            // Set timer which handles sending further reads until trigger is released
            this.ReaderTimer.Interval = 2000;
            this.ReaderTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
        else if ( e.NewState == Symbol.RFID.TriggerState.RELEASED )
        {
            this.StatusLabel.Text = "Press trigger to read RFID tags";

            // Disable the timer
            this.ReaderTimer.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Submits a new read at every timer tick
    /// </summary>
    private void ReaderTimer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // If another RFID operation has not already started
        if (!this.MyReader.Info.IsBusy)
        {
            // Start a new read
            this.StartRead();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Read complete or failure notification
    /// </summary>
    private void MyReader_ReadNotify(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the next ReaderData
        Symbol.RFID.ReaderData TheReaderData =
            (Symbol.RFID.ReaderData)this.MyReader.GetNextReaderData();

        // If it is a successful read (as opposed to a failed one)
        if ( TheReaderData.Result == Symbol.Results.SUCCESS )
        {
            // Handle the data from this read
            this.HandleData(TheReaderData);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle data from the reader
    /// </summary>
    private void HandleData(Symbol.RFID.ReaderData TheReaderData)
    {
        // Clear the previous list
        this.ReaderDataListView.Items.Clear();

        // Populate the list with the updated data
        for (int i=0; i<MyReaderData.TagList.TotalTags; i++)
        {
            string[] sItems = new string[] 
                                {
                                    i.ToString(), 
                                    MyReaderData.TagList[i].ToString(), 
                                    MyReaderData.TagList[i].ReadCount.ToString()
                                };

            this.ReaderDataListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(sItems));
        }

        // Clear the flag so that the Taglist is maintained
        ClearListFlag = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the Inventory list on the form and sets the flag to
    /// start a new inventory.
    /// </summary>
    private void btnClearList_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear the previous list
        this.ReaderDataListView.Items.Clear();

        // Set the flag to notify StartRead to start a new inventory
        ClearListFlag = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Exits the application.
    /// </summary>
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Close this form
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnClearList_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Checks if the key pressed was an enter button (character code 13)
        if (e.KeyValue == (char)13)
            btnClearList_Click(this, e);
    }

    private void btnExit_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Checks if the key pressed was an enter button (character code 13)
        if (e.KeyValue == (char)13)
            btnExit_Click(this, e);
    }

    private void ReaderForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ReaderDataListView.Focus();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when ReaderForm is activated
    /// </summary>
    private void ReaderForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Enable the trigger
        if (this.MyReader != null)
            this.MyReader.TriggerNotify += this.MyTriggerHandler;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when ReaderForm is deactivated
    /// </summary>
    private void ReaderForm_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Disable the trigger
        if (this.MyReader != null)
            this.MyReader.TriggerNotify -= this.MyTriggerHandler;
    }

    private void ReaderForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bInitialScale == true)
        {
            return; // Return if the initial scaling (from scratch)is not complete.
        }

        if (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width > Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height) // If landscape orientation
        {
            if (bPortrait != false) // If an orientation change has occured to landscape
            {
                bPortrait = false; // Set the orientation flag accordingly.
                bInitialScale = true; // An initial scaling is required due to orientation change.
                Scale(this); // Scale the GUI.
            }
            else
            {   // No orientation change has occured
                bSkipMaxLen = true; // Initial scaling is now complete, so skipping the max. length restriction is now possible.
                Scale(this); // Scale the GUI.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Similarly for the portrait orientation...
            if (bPortrait != true)
            {
                bPortrait = true;
                bInitialScale = true;
                Scale(this);
            }
            else
            {
                bSkipMaxLen = true;
                Scale(this);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Изначально грешил на этот фрагмент кода:

```
// Set timer which handles sending further reads until trigger is released
        this.ReaderTimer.Interval = 2000;
        this.ReaderTimer.Enabled = true;
```

Но установка интервала в 0 не решает проблему. Причем за за время начала считывания по нажатию "курка", до появления считанных меток в списке, метки успевают считаться 20+ раз.

Comment: А вы уверенны, что задержку возможно нивелировать? Возможно ли что задержка на аппаратной стороне? Не пробовали в коде расставить таймеры и выяснить который кусок вызывает задержку?

Comment: Есть демонстрационная программа, там считывание происходит в течении пары секунд на той же аппаратной части, а не в течении 15-30сек. Расставлять таймеры не пробовал, подскажете пример?

Comment: Ну, создаёте таймер: System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); И перед куском кода время выполнения которого хотите замерять вызываете sw.Restart(); После конца измеряемого куска ставите sw.Stop(); После выполнения этой строчки в sw будут значения  sw.Elapsed  sw.ElapsedMilliseconds  sw.ElapsedTicks хранящие замерянное время в секундах, миллисекундах и тиках соответственно. Если доступна отладка по точкам останова то я бы ставил брейкпоинты на строчку следом за sw.Stop(); и смотрел результат но можно и по другому. Это уже от предпочтений и условий зависит.